# tar: julia-xxx: Cannot create symlink to xxx: Operation not supported

Tags: azure, installation, julia

Trying to install Julia on a machine with the following specification:

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-1090-azure
Architecture: x86-64

I ran:

tar -xvzf julia-1.6.7-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

and got several error messages that look like these:

julia-1.6.7/lib/libjulia.so
tar: julia-1.6.7/lib/libjulia.so: cannot create symlink to ‘libjulia.so.1.6’: operation not supported

julia-1.6.7/lib/julia/libgfortran.so
tar: julia-1.6.7/lib/julia/libgfortran.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘libgfortran.so.4.0.0’: Operation not supported

Any suggestion on how to solve these error messages are much appreciated.

Comment: Most likely you are trying to unpack Julia on a drive with partition type that does not allow for symlinks. What does the command `df -Th` show?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel, perhaps you could change that comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The typical problem is that not all operating systems are supporting symlinks.

Try `df -Th` and look what is going on with the drive you are trying to install:

```
root@LGPSZ:~# df -Th
Filesystem     Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sdc       ext4    1007G  8.0G  948G   1% /
...
```

In the example above my root drive is an `ext4` type which supports symlinks.

On the other hand a Windows file system could be mounted on your Linux machine which type is denoted as `ntfs` or `vfat`. Those file system do not support symbolic links and hence the `tar` command will fail.

P.S.

[ugly workaround for desperate cases] If you really need to use `ntfs` partition on a Linux system a brutal workaround could be untarring the file on an `ext4` file system and then tarring it again using `--deference` option - in that case you would get a `tar` archive without symlniks (I have not tested it with Julia though but should work).